# Вызов Base Event из класса наследника

Tags: c#, события

В главном классе есть ивент, от этого класса наследуем еще пару классов. Как в этих класса - наследниках вызвать ивент базового класса?

Comment: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hy3sefw3][1]

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hy3sefw3

Comment: а с каким модификатором доступа метод OnRaiseНазавниеСобытия? и вообще привидите код, касающийся родительского события

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю как то так:

```
    public class A
    {
        public event StandartDelegat masterEvent;

        protected void OnMasterEvent(StandartDelegatArgs args)
        {
            StandartDelegat handler = masterEvent;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, args);
        }
    }

    public class B:A
    {
        public void InvokeParentEvent()
        {
            base.OnMasterEvent(new StandartDelegatArgs());//но в данном случае base не обязателен т.к. у нас не определён в классе B метод OnMasterEvent
        }
    }
```

Comment: не очень пример:

правильнее будет:

    protected virtual void OnMasterEvent(StandartDelegatArgs args){}
    ...
    protected override void OnMasterEvent(StandartDelegatArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMasterEvent(e);
    }

Comment: А где в вопросе написано что нам надо переопределить евент?

Comment: Проблема то в том что вызвать конструкцию if (handler != null) handler(this, args); нельзя вызвать в наследники если евент базового класса

Comment: префикс `base.` как раз и говорит о базовом классе, так что ничего не переопределено

Comment: В данном случае это будет избыточно. Но для примера, согласен можно указать. Для чего инвокер евента делать виртуальным - не понимаю. Это только запутает, на мой взгляд.

Comment: 'префикс base. как раз и говорит о базовом классе, так что ничего не переопределено' - в вашем примере как раз без префикса base и произойдёт бесконечная рекурсия т.к. вы переопределяете OnMasterEvent

Answer (score -1):

Можно скрыть родитескую реализацию с помощью модификатора new и использовать так же как если бы ты использовал в родительском классе :)

```
public class B:A
    {
        new public event StandartDelegat masterEvent;
        public void InvokeParentEvent()
        {
            masterEvent?.Invoke(...);
        }
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Есть два способа. **Первый.** Просто удалить модификатор event! Нужно учесть, что после этого запуск события может быть доступен извне.

Возьмём стандартный пример из документации [How to raise base class events in derived classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-raise-base-class-events-in-derived-classes) и модифицируем его:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BaseClassEvents
{
    // Special EventArgs class to hold info about Shapes.
    public class ShapeEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private double area;
        public ShapeEventArgs(double aea) { area = aea; }
        public double NewArea { get { return area; } }
    }
    // Base class event publisher
    public abstract class Shape
    {
        protected double _area;
        public double Area { get { return _area; } set { _area = value; } }
        // The event. Note that by using the generic EventHandler<T> event type
        // we do not need to declare a separate delegate type.
        public EventHandler<ShapeEventArgs> ShapeChanged; // ЭТО ЗДЕСЬ! убрали event
        public abstract void Draw();
        //The event-invoking method that derived classes can override.
        protected virtual void OnShapeChanged(ShapeEventArgs e) // ЭТО БОЛЬШЕ НЕ НУЖНО!
        {
            // Safely raise the event for all subscribers
            ShapeChanged.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
    public class Circle : Shape
    {
        private double _radius;
        public Circle(double radius)
        {
            _radius = radius;
            _area = 3.14 * _radius * _radius;
        }
        public void Update(double d)
        {
            _radius = d;
            _area = 3.14 * _radius * _radius;
            ShapeChanged(this, new ShapeEventArgs(_area)); // ЗАПУСКАЕМ СОБЫТИЕ НАПРЯМУЮ!
        }
        protected override void OnShapeChanged(ShapeEventArgs e) // ЭТО БОЛЬШЕ НЕ НУЖНО!
        {
            // Do any circle-specific processing here.
            // Call the base class event invocation method.
            base.OnShapeChanged(e);
        }
        public override void Draw() { Console.WriteLine("Drawing a circle"); }
    }
    public class Rectangle : Shape
    {
        private double _length, _width;
        public Rectangle(double length, double width)
        {
            _length = length; _width = width; _area = _length * _width;
        }
        public void Update(double length, double width)
        {
            _length = length; _width = width; _area = _length * _width;
            ShapeChanged(this, new ShapeEventArgs(_area)); // ЗАПУСКАЕМ СОБЫТИЕ НАПРЯМУЮ!
        }
        protected override void OnShapeChanged(ShapeEventArgs e) // ЭТО БОЛЬШЕ НЕ НУЖНО!

        }
             // Do any rectangle-specific processing here.
            // Call the base class event invocation method.
            base.OnShapeChanged(e);
        }
    public override void Draw() { Console.WriteLine("Drawing a rectangle"); }
        }
        // Represents the surface on which the shapes are drawn
        // Subscribes to shape events so that it knows
        // when to redraw a shape.
        public class ShapeContainer
    {
        private readonly List<Shape> _list;
        public ShapeContainer() { _list = new List<Shape>(); }
        public void AddShape(Shape shape)
        {
            _list.Add(shape);
            // Subscribe to the base class event.
            shape.ShapeChanged += HandleShapeChanged;
        }
        // ...Other methods to draw, resize, etc.
        private void HandleShapeChanged(object sender, ShapeEventArgs e)
        {
            // Diagnostic message for demonstration purposes.
            Console.WriteLine("Received event. Shape area is now " + e.NewArea);
            // Redraw the shape here.
            ((Shape)sender).Draw();
        }
    }
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //Create the event publishers and subscriber
            var circle = new Circle(54);
            var rectangle = new Rectangle(12, 9);
            var container = new ShapeContainer();
            // Add the shapes to the container.
            container.AddShape(circle);
            container.AddShape(rectangle);
            // Cause some events to be raised.
            circle.Update(57);
            rectangle.Update(7, 7);
            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Второй** способ - сделать событие виртуальным, а в наследниках переопределять его. Тот же самый пример с использованием virtual/override:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BaseClassEvents{
    // Special EventArgs class to hold info about Shapes.
    public class ShapeEventArgs : EventArgs{
        private double area;
        public ShapeEventArgs(double aea) { area = aea; }
        public double NewArea { get { return area; } } }
 
    // Base class event publisher
    public abstract class Shape{
        protected double _area;
        public double Area{  get { return _area; } set { _area = value; } }
        // The event. Note that by using the generic EventHandler<T> event type
        // we do not need to declare a separate delegate type.
        public virtual event EventHandler<ShapeEventArgs> ShapeChanged; // ЭТО ЗДЕСЬ!
        public abstract void Draw();
        //The event-invoking method that derived classes can override.
        protected virtual void OnShapeChanged(ShapeEventArgs e) // ЭТО БОЛЬШЕ НЕ НУЖНО!
        {
            // Safely raise the event for all subscribers
            ShapeChanged.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }

    public class Circle : Shape{
        private double _radius;
        public Circle(double radius){
            _radius = radius;
            _area = 3.14 * _radius * _radius;
        }
        public void Update(double d){
            _radius = d;
            _area = 3.14 * _radius * _radius;
            ShapeChanged(this, new ShapeEventArgs(_area)); // ЗАПУСКАЕМ СОБЫТИЕ НАПРЯМУЮ!
        }
        protected override void OnShapeChanged(ShapeEventArgs e){ // ЭТО БОЛЬШЕ НЕ НУЖНО!
            // Do any circle-specific processing here.
            // Call the base class event invocation method.
            base.OnShapeChanged(e);
        }
        public override event EventHandler<ShapeEventArgs> ShapeChanged; // ЭТО ЗДЕСЬ!
        public override void Draw() { Console.WriteLine("Drawing a circle"); }
    }

    public class Rectangle : Shape{
        private double _length, _width;
        public Rectangle(double length, double width){
            _length = length; _width = width; _area = _length * _width;
        }
        public void Update(double length, double width){
            _length = length; _width = width; _area = _length * _width;
            ShapeChanged(this, new ShapeEventArgs(_area)); // ЗАПУСКАЕМ СОБЫТИЕ НАПРЯМУЮ!
        }
        protected override void OnShapeChanged(ShapeEventArgs e){ // ЭТО БОЛЬШЕ НЕ НУЖНО!
             // Do any rectangle-specific processing here.
            // Call the base class event invocation method.
            base.OnShapeChanged(e);
        }
        public override event EventHandler<ShapeEventArgs> ShapeChanged; // ЭТО ЗДЕСЬ!
        public override void Draw() { Console.WriteLine("Drawing a rectangle"); }
    }
    // Represents the surface on which the shapes are drawn
    // Subscribes to shape events so that it knows
    // when to redraw a shape.
    public class ShapeContainer{
        private readonly List<Shape> _list;
        public ShapeContainer() { _list = new List<Shape>(); }
        public void AddShape(Shape shape) {
            _list.Add(shape);
            // Subscribe to the base class event.
            shape.ShapeChanged += HandleShapeChanged;
        }
        // ...Other methods to draw, resize, etc.
        private void HandleShapeChanged(object sender, ShapeEventArgs e){
               // Diagnostic message for demonstration purposes.
                Console.WriteLine("Received event. Shape area is now " + e.NewArea);
                // Redraw the shape here.
                ((Shape)sender).Draw();
        }
    }

    class Test{
        static void Main(){
            //Create the event publishers and subscriber
            var circle = new Circle(54);
            var rectangle = new Rectangle(12, 9);
            var container = new ShapeContainer();
            // Add the shapes to the container.
            container.AddShape(circle);
            container.AddShape(rectangle);
            // Cause some events to be raised.
            circle.Update(57);
            rectangle.Update(7, 7);
           // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: _`public EventHandler<ShapeEventArgs> ShapeChanged;` // ЭТО ЗДЕСЬ! убрали event_ - а по ссылке из ответа `event` на месте

Comment: @Grundy не пойму смысл комментария. Ссылка на документацию, там пример с использованием event, естественно, коли речь о том, как его применять. У меня тот же самый пример, но без модификатора event, что решает поставленный вопрос.

Comment: Сейчас выглядит так, будто приведен текст из примера, который решает проблему в вопросе. И раздел справки совпадает с вопросом.